# The sound of the phone is cut off due to the steam in the bathroom

Tags: audio

My phone's media is muted! I put the phone next to the mirror in the bathroom this morning and when I came back several hours later I realized I couldn't hear music or videos.I can hear the phone ringing and the alert sound, which means media and notifications are muted, and the alarm and ringtone are fine. I whistle to someone, incomprehensible and vague sounds are played.When someone calls me, I don't hear his voice and he doesn't hear me either. I don't know what caused this but what should I do?

I find it surprising that I can hear calls and alarms, and it indicates that the notification and media sounds are muted.